# AngularJs $watch function n,o doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I haven't been able to find an answer to this, mostly because wording it is kind of hard.  What I have is my new change and old change.  I know for a fact that the old change should be different but it randomly is the same as the new change.  Here is my code:

```
$scope.$watch(function() { return partNumber }, function(n,o) {
        $http.get(afHttp.baseUrl + "/" + $scope.partName + "/" + n)
            .success(function(data) {
                console.log(n);
                console.log(o);
                $scope.grid.data = data;
            });
    });
```

So I know for a fact the old part is different and I guess updating too fast perhaps? If I was on part 1 and changed to part 2 it would console log 2 2.  I don't know why can anyone help?

Comment: How does `partNumber` get updated?

Answer (score 0):

maybe it is

```
return $scope.partNumber
```

instead of

```
return partNumber
```

if you can provide some more code, it could be useful.